# fopen returns NULL ONLY after adding entries to structure array

Tags: c

I am doing an assignment for school and I keep getting my fopen function returning NULL.  **Please keep in mind that this write_info function was working perfectly before I was required to start using dynamic arrays instead of statically defined ones.**

Here are my main declarations:

```
void main(void)
{
    struct assignment *assi = NULL;
    char choice;
    int choice_check = TRUE;
    int loop = TRUE, keep_loop = TRUE;
    int nbr_asst = 0;
    char asst_file[] = "C:\\Users\\Main\\Documents\\asst.txt";
    int nbr_asstfile = 0;
```

Here is the function call:

```
write_info(asst_file, assi, nbr_asstfile);
```

And here is the actual function:

```
void write_info(char asst_file[], struct assignment *asst_data, 
    int nbr_asstfile)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int count;

    fptr = fopen(asst_file, "w");
    if (fptr != NULL)
    {


        fwrite(&nbr_asstfile, sizeof(nbr_asstfile), 1, fptr);

        for (count = 0; count < nbr_asstfile; count++)
        {
            fwrite(&asst_data[count], sizeof(asst_data[count]), 1, fptr);
        }
        fclose(fptr);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Problem opening the file!");
    }

    return;
}
```

If I simply run the function after reading in from the text file, there is no problem to rewrite everything.  However, if I add one entry to my structure, the fptr returns NULL when I try to write.  Anybody know why?

I really hope I am asking this in a way that people can understand, and if you need any extra info please let me know.  I didn't want to post the entire program because it is 505 lines.

Thank you to all in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `errno`?

Comment: In what you posted, after `struct assignment *assi = NULL;` that `NULL` is passed to `write_info` for `*asst_data` argument, which then does `fwrite(&asst_data[count], sizeof(asst_data[count]), 1, fptr);` which is nonsense since nothing is known about a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: You really need to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]) so that we can see whether you're doing anything to `assi` or `nbr_asstfile` between when you initialize them to 0 and call the writing function.